# How to query Azure SQL backups

Tags: azure-sql-database

I’m looking for documentation on how to run a query against Azure to see when backups were run and what is available to restore from. In an on prem solution this is easy but I have no idea where this info is stored on Azure SQL DB.

Answer (score 3):

It's not stored in any way. Instead you need to look to the service tier to know how far back you have backup retention. The actual schedule of the backups isn't published because it can vary. After the initial backup is taken, they do differentials and log backups, but you can't see when they happened. You can read more [about it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups).